# Meteor JS - sharing Collections among distinct clients (like Admin portal vs Consumer portal)

Tags: meteor, architecture

A few similar (but not same) questions were asked 2 years ago but not 100% answered..

([Segmented Meteor App(s) - loading only half the client or two apps sharing a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606169/segmented-meteor-apps-loading-only-half-the-client-or-two-apps-sharing-a-dat?rq=1) ;

[Meteor: Different collections, different databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739250/meteor-different-collections-different-databases/15743448#15743448))

Since Meteor has changed quite a bit, was wondering if there was a better way of doing the following (i know about roles, publish subscribe etc):

**Simple example:** Say I have a restaurant ordering app with 2 portals:

**(1) Consumer side,** with accounts, and a form for your food order & pay for it w/ credit card (assume # is stored, not using Stripe etc).

**(2) Admin side,** with accounts, for the restaurant to manage incoming orders & track payments, see credit card numbers.

*Assuming more complexity + very high security requirements*, would this be structured as 1 monolithic meteor app? Or is there a standard way to break it into 2 (like traditional MVC frameworks, you might have 3 DBs - 1 Consumer DB, 1 Admin DB, **1 DB for shared sensitive data like credit card numbers** - and 2 SPA clients). Breaking it into 2 would be preferable for the following reasons:

**(1)** different account types for the 2 portals - e.g. admins require 2FA. I also actually prefer to have separate DBs for security & backup precautions.

**(2)** useful for code management/distribution purposes

**(3)** also so we don't have to send all the Admin templates to the Consumer.

Comment: More than anything else - I'm asking if there is a **standard** way of doing this that fits **Meteor** specifically - i.e. not just what could/couldn't work. (i.e. a possible answer is simply "No")

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be able to use two Meteor apps accessing the same Mongo database.